# R - dplyr sum with group by from the function

Tags: r, dplyr

Load data from the advertising cabinet and then I want to aggregate it, get the sum of three columns and write it in csv. I checked out a few lessons on the dplyr library, but unfortunately I still get an error when trying to summarize columns. I think I'm somehow using the column names incorrectly. Appreciate any tips on how to do it correctly

> Error in UseMethod("group_by") : there is no suitable method for
> 'group_by' applied to an object of the "character" class

```
print(Sys.time())
        
library(rfacebookstat)
fb_token="###"
accs<-fbGetAdAccounts(
source_id=###, 

api_version='v13.0', 
access_token=fb_token)
    
fb_data_new <- fbGetMarketingStat(api_version='v13.0',
 accounts_id = accs$id,
 level = "ad",

 fields = "date_start,
   account_id,
   account_name,
   campaign_id, 
   campaign_name,
   adset_id, 
   adset_name, 
   ad_id, 
   ad_name, 
   impressions,
   clicks,
   cpc,
   spend",
breakdowns = "region, country",
date_start = Sys.Date()-1,
date_stop  = Sys.Date()-1, 
access_token = fb_token)
        
        
#install.packages("dplyr")
library("dplyr")

#_________________

fb_report_SUM %>% 

group_by(fb_data_new$date_start,
   fb_data_new$account_id,
   fb_data_new$account_name,
   fb_data_new$campaign_id, 
   fb_data_new$campaign_name,
   fb_data_new$adset_id, 
   fb_data_new$adset_name, 
   fb_data_new$ad_id, 
   fb_data_new$ad_name, 
   fb_data_new$region, 
   fb_data_new$country) %>% 
summarise(across(everything(), sum))

#csv
write.csv(fb_report_SUM, file="fb_report_summarize.csv")
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fb_report_SUM <- fb_data_new %>% 
  group_by(date_start,
           account_id,....)
```